# .NET Core 2.1 - My code does not appear in VS2017 stack trace

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I am developing a .NET Core 2.1 console application using dependency injection (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection). The code looks something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        //...

        var configuration = GetConfiguration();
        var serviceProvider = ConfigureServices(configuration);

        var importer = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataImporter>();

        var result = await importer.ImportCentersAndStores(fileName);

        //...
    }

    private static IConfigurationRoot GetConfiguration()
    {
        return new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
    }

    private static ServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IConfigurationRoot configuration)
    {
        System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

        return new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddConfiguration(configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                builder.AddConsole();
            })
            .AddOptions()
            .AddAutoMapper()
            .AddDatabase(configuration.GetConnectionString("Blah"))
            .AddTransient<DataImporter>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

The `DataImporter` class and the `ImportCentersAndStores` method are nothing special - it does various stuff including reading an Excel file and does some logging. I don't think the nature of that code is relevant.

Now the problem is that whenever an exception is thrown inside the `DataImporter` class, the stack trace has no frames with my code:

[image: My useless call stack]

The debugging display looks like this:

[image: My useless debugging display]

This happens whether I catch the thrown exception or not. The above exception happens within a method in `DataImporter` called from `ImportCentersAndStores`. So there should be two frames of my code there.

There is no context for debugging. I cannot inspect variables or anything.

I have no idea what `System.Private.CoreLib` is or why it hogs most of the call stack. I do not know if the problem is actually related to my use of DI.

Just My Code makes no difference. Exception settings are default. I cannot see any debugging options that should do this.

In case you wonder: I have included this in the project file to enable the async Main method:

```
<LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: You can enable to stop on all exceptions on CLR option using `CTRL+ALT+E` so the place at which your code blows up VS will stop the code. The stack trace thing is crap and caused by async... because the code is running on another stack in another process.. common problem with threading. I think VS2019 is supposed to bring something better in. You can also try and enable source link.. it will let you step into those dll's code by downloading source from Microsoft but that still wont solve the stack problem

Comment: The problem with `async` stack traces is actually due to developer misunderstandings. The stack trace does *not* tell you where your code came from - and it *never did*. The stack trace tells you where your code is *returning to*. It just happens that these are the same for synchronous code, so devs got used to the stack trace telling them *how they got somewhere* (i.e., the causality chain). In the asynchronous world, the causality chain and the stack trace are different things; they only have the same values in the synchronous world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the second screenshot: Exception helper (popup) -> View details -> Stack trace. This will be the correct stack trace at the time the exception was thrown before the `async` sausage kicked in.

So - yes - this behavior is because of your `async` stuff. Which honestly makes me curious why would you ever do anything `async` in **console** application?

Comment: Mike, there are loot of uses cases:
1. The obvious one: calling something async. 
2. Building an event listener, which communicates e.g. via RabbitMq

Comment: The wy is simple: I am injecting and using stuff from another assembly (the AddDatabase line in ConfigureServices). There is some async stuff there which is easier to call from an async method.

Comment: But you are saying this is all because of async? But that doesn't usually have these consequences...?

Comment: I'll ditch the asyncs and see what happens.

Comment: @TorHaugen Yeah, that makes sense if you have to work with already existing async method. I think if you `.RunSynchronously()` that task _and_ you have symbols in place it should work. But true with regards to what **pumpkin**  said, depends also on stop-on-exceptions dialog setup.

Comment: Yup. Asyncs were trolling me. Seems like the debugger doesn't handle them so well for console apps as for eg. ASP.NET Core.